# jquery: fadeToggle everything but not links and special div's

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, fade

I would like to fadeToggle everything in the div `container` but not links and not the div with the class `to_top`. But with the following code everything in the div `container` fadetoggles. Where I'm wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$("#container").not(".to_top", "a").on('tap', function(e) {
    $("#headline").fadeToggle(700);
    $("#headline_tap").fadeToggle();
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="fileadmin/js/menue.js"></script>
  <script src="fileadmin/js/tap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="menue"></div>
 <div id="headline">
   <div id="menueicon"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="headline_tap">
     <div id="menueicon"></div>
 </div>   
 <div id="container">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="topimage"></div>
    </div>   
    <div id="content">
       <p class="bodytext">...Im Falle der Aktivierung der ...</p>
       <p class="bodytext">Die im Rahmen... dem folgenden Link verfügbare
          Browser-Plugin herunterladen und installieren:&nbsp;<a            
            href="http://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de" target="_blank">Link</a>.
      </p>
    <a href="impressum/#top" title="Zum Seitenanfang" class="to_top"><img src="/fileadmin/images/mobile/to_top.png"></a>


 <div id="footer"></div>
 </div>
   <div id="footline"></div>  
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You probably meant to put that comma _inside_ the selector: `not(".to_top,a")`

Comment: `.not` doesn't search inside the container. It removes matching elements from the previous collection.

Comment: Oh, I think you are right; I corrected the code. But it doesn't work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found it:

```
$("#container").on("tap", function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (!target.is('a')) {
    $("#headline").fadeToggle(700);
    $("#headline_tap").fadeToggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
$('#container :not(".to_top, a")').on('tap', function(e) {  
    $("#headline").fadeToggle(700);
    $("#headline_tap").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$("#container :not(.to_top,a)").on('tap', ...);
```

You're applying `.not()` to just the `#container` DIV, not the elements inside it.

When you click on the link, the click event bubbles out to the containing elements. So even though the event is not bound on the link, it's still bound on the `<p>` around the link. In order to prevent this, you need to add a handler on the excluded elements that disables propagation:

```
$("#container .to_top, #container a").on("tap", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You should also use `stopPropagation` in your main handler. Otherwise, the headlines toggle once for the original element you clicked on, then again for its container, and so on.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/NA5AL/7/) -- I use `click` instead of `tap` so it can be used with ordinary browsers.

Comment: Can you show your HTML, and explain which elements you should and shouldn't be able to tap on to get this effect?

Comment: Now I added the html to my question above. Everything in the div "container" should be able to be tapped on but not the links in the text and not the link to the top.

Comment: While you can't click on the link, you can tap on the image inside the link, because it isn't included in `:not`.